# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query where I am counting rows but it's showing this error..

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from=? AND to=?' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\network\profile.php on line 38
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from=? AND to=?' at line 1 in C:\wamp\www\network\profile.php on line 38

Here's my code :

```
$sql_check_friend = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM connection_request WHERE from=:me AND"; 
$sql_check_friend .= "to=:friend";
    
$sth = $db->prepare($sql_check_friend);
$sth->bindParam(":me", $me);
$sth->bindParam(":friend", $pageuserid);
$sth->execute();

$count = $sth->fetchColumn();

if($count > 0){
echo "REQUEST SENT";
}else{
echo "NOT SENT";
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong..

Comment: You're missing `";` on your 1st line, and a `"` on your 2nd line.

Comment: i broke the code up here.. on my editor it's on one line.. I will edit this one though..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`from` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). It must be escaped in your query:

```
 SELECT ... WHERE `from` := ...
                  ^--  ^---
```

And ditto for `to` as well - it's a reserved word too.

Comment: @jorge: probably just a typo here, otherwise there'd be far more sql errors and php syntax errors to boot.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your string/text connection may contain quotes like this: `"`,`'` or `` ` ``. try removing these quotes and then execute query, so validate your connection string.