# CKEditor Upload code snippet - SQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ckeditor

I'm having trouble uploading code snippets from CKEditor. They are formatted fine, however when uploading to the database it views the text as code and stops once hitting an '$' variable.
This is the output from CKEditor for a code snippet

```html
<pre>
<code class="language-php">
 echo $hello
</code></pre>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

And this is whats used to post to the database

```html
$date = date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
$now = time(); $utc_time = $now - intval(date('Z', $now));
$time = date('H:i:s', $now);

$name = $_POST['title'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$forum_id = $_POST['forum_id'];
$post = $_POST['post'];


$user_id = $_SESSION['user']['user_id'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO threads (forum_id,user_id,name,post,time,date,subject) VALUES ('$forum_id','$user_id','$name','".$post."','$time','$date','$subject');";
```

And the error is:

```html
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'echo $hello' in /storage/www/fsociety/newthread.php on line 72
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'echo $hello' at line 1 in /storage/www/fsociety/newthread.php on line 72
```

Comment: Did you check it before asking ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866339/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-pdoexception-with-message-sqlstate42000 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367445/uncaught-exception-pdoexception-with-message-sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode HTML entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713449/encode-html-entities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving, you should encode html like this

```
$post = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post']);
```